# How do I kill the container process (PID 1) from inside the container using bash/sh shell

Tags: bash, docker

I have a scenario where I have a shell script which is run using `crond`. I need to exit the container if that particular script fails. Seems like `SIGKILL` doesn't work with PID 1.

How do I kill the container process (PID 1) from inside the container using bash/sh shell?

Minimal example -

Dockerfile -

```
FROM alpine:3.5

ENV LOGS_DIR="/rest/logs/" CRON_LOG_FILE="${LOGS_DIR}/cron.log"

RUN apk add --update python py-pip zip bash && \
    pip install awscli && \
    mkdir -p ${LOGS_DIR} && \
    touch ${CRON_LOG_FILE}

COPY ./lr-s3.sh ./lr-entry.sh ./install_crontab.txt ./files_to_rotate.txt ./

RUN chmod +x /lr-s3.sh /lr-entry.sh && \
    crontab install_crontab.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["/lr-entry.sh"]
```

Entrypoint -

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGS_DIR="${LOGS_DIR:-/rest/logs}"
CRON_LOG_FILE="${LOGS_DIR}/cron.log"

mkdir -p ${LOGS_DIR}
touch ${CRON_LOG_FILE}

ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 ${CRON_LOG_FILE}

echo "Cron [Starting]"
exec crond -c /var/spool/cron/crontabs -f -L ${CRON_LOG_FILE} "$@"
```

Script to run via Cron -

```
aws s3 cp ${LOGS_DIR}/${FL_NAME} s3://${BKTNAME}/${FL_NAME}

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "S3 Backup Failed"
    pkill crond
    exit 1
fi
```

`pkill crond` doesn't work inside the script, it has PID 1.

If container restarts or doesn't exist, we will come to know that there is an issue with the container or the script.

Comment: @Cyrus - The duplicate doesn't have an accepted answer. I cannot let the shell script run as foreground process and manage other processes. I haven't yet got any answers to my question.

Comment: @Cyrus - Can you please reopen this?

Comment: Okay. Good luck.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Updated with minimal code.

Comment: I did some google and found out that PID 1 is protected. Just want to know if there is any hack to make it through.

Comment: `pkill crond doesn't work` does it print an error message? What is the reason? What docker container to use to test it? There is always `--privileged`, does it work with it?

Comment: Added Dockerfile. I just tried in `--privileged` but no luck.

Comment: I can thing of a workaround solution - mount the docker socket  from host to the container, run with `--privileged` and execute `docker kill` on yourself when backup fails. But this should be basically the same as `pkill -KILL ctond`. And feels like there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: Yes, mounting docker socket or even docker inside docker seems like overkill. Even I feel there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: Killing process 1 just does not sound like a good idea to whatever it is that you want to do. If you want the container to exit, killing the process you started (`crond`) should suffice.

Comment: As an aside, comparing `$?` to zero is an antipattern. You simply want `if ! aws s3 cp things; then echo Fail >&2; fi`

Comment: Also you can't `pkill crond` *after* you `exit 1`

Answer (score 4):

> How do I kill the container process (PID 1) from inside the container using bash/sh shell?

PID 1 is protected, so you can't kill it, but you can setup a signal handler for it:

```
 # somewhere in entrypoint
 trap "exit" SIGINT SIGTERM
```

after that, the process will `exit` if you sent a `kill -s SIGINT 1` from another process inside the container.

Comment: As the script executes `exec`, this trap will never fire, cause `exec` clears signal handlers. However if OP removes `exec`, this maybe probably would allow to execute custom command on signal as PID1, thus will allow PID1 to asynchronously execute any action, ex. kill `crond`.

Comment: For *bash* it is enough to use `trap "exit"` and then `kill -s SIGINT 1`. I didn't need specify any signals for the `trap` command. For *sh* i got it to run with `trap 'exit'` and `kill -2 1`